# java easy ifs worng output

Tags: java, if-statement

I am new to java, and currently Im playing around with simple if statments. I have two questions. 
x
First one: if answer yes, the last statment "You need to answer yes or no" is printed anyway. I only want it to print if the answer is something other than yes or no.

Second question. If I answer "maybe" (or something that is not yes/no the system print "You have to answer yes or no" and quits. How can a jump back to the first line and ask "are you doing good) once more?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ovingto {
  public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Are you doing good?");
    String ord = keyboard.nextLine();

    if (ord.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
      System.out.println ("nice to hear!");
    }

    if (ord.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
      System.out.println ("that makes me sad!");
    } else {
      System.out.println ("you need to  answer yes or no");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you are missing an `else` before the second `if`. It should be `else if (ord.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))` Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: And you need a basic `while` loop.

Comment: I dont get how I could have written the question differently to make it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to both the questions ..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true) {
        System.out.printf("Are you doing good?");
        String ord = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (ord.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
           System.out.println ("nice to hear!");
           break;
        }

        else if (ord.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            System.out.println ("that makes me sad!");
            break;
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("you need to  answer yes or no");
        }
    }
}
```

to redirect use the above code.. also there are many other ways to do it

Comment: When I run the program with your edits I get a error Scanner can not be resolved to type? What do I need to do to change that?

Comment: did u import the Scanner from java.util.Scanner

Comment: hehehehe, of course I did not, and that answered the question :) thanx

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain your if/else statements to achieve the effect you want.

Change the code to look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ovingto {
    public static void main (String [] args){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Are you doing good?");
        String ord = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (ord.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            System.out.println ("nice to hear!");
        }

        else if (ord.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            System.out.println ("that makes me sad!");
        }

       else {
           System.out.println ("you need to  answer yes or no");
       }


   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `else`.

try,

```
if (ord.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    System.out.println ("nice to hear!");
}

else if (ord.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
    System.out.println ("that makes me sad!");
}

else {
    System.out.println ("you need to  answer yes or no");
}
```

For the 2nd question the best choice is a `do-While` loop.